# GDBserver on Qemu not honoring "follow-fork-mode child"

Tags: gdb, mips, qemu

I am using `gdb-multiarch` version 9.1 on Ubuntu to connect to a `qemu-mipsel-static` version 4.2.0 running a MIPS application which daemonizes itself with `fork()`, and which is running the built-in `gdbserver`. Here is the relevant GDB output:

```
Breakpoint 5, 0x7f5bb874 in daemon () from ./lib/libc.so.0
```

The next instruction is `jalr` to `fork`

```
(gdb) si
0x7f5738e0 in fork () from ./lib/libc.so.0
```

Now we are in `fork()`, let's check the state of `follow-fork-mode`

```
(gdb) show follow-fork-mode 
Debugger response to a program call of fork or vfork is "child".
```

Everything looks good, let's finish the function and check our return value

```
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  0x7f5738e0 in fork () from ./lib/libc.so.0
0x7f5bb87c in daemon () from ./lib/libc.so.0
(gdb) p $v0
$7 = 119052
(gdb) # what
```

The PID indicates we are still attached to the parent process

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html):

> On most systems, GDB has no special support for debugging programs
> which create additional processes using the fork function. When a
> program forks, GDB will continue to debug the parent process and the
> child process will run unimpeded. If you have set a breakpoint in any
> code which the child then executes, the child will get a SIGTRAP
> signal which (unless it catches the signal) will cause it to
> terminate.

> On some systems, GDB provides support for debugging programs that
> create additional processes using the fork or vfork functions. On
> GNU/Linux platforms, this feature is supported with kernel version
> 2.5.46 and later.

Could it be that your kernel version is too low?

You can also try [`catch fork/vfork/exec`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_30.html)  commands.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It wasn't the kernel version, as it was running on a recent Ubuntu release. Even Ubuntu 4.10 (Warty Warthog), the first Ubuntu released, used a newer kernel than 2.5.4.